# virtualhost not using htaccess on fedora 19

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, fedora

I've recently switched over to a fedora 19 cloud server service and got most things squared away except for htaccess. Am I doing this wrong or missing something?

This is what i have updated in my httpd.conf file

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```

And Here is my VirtualHost telling it what folder structure and which file to use for htaccess

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs
   ServerName www.domain.com
   ServerAlias www.domain.com
   <Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/vhosts/>
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
   </Directory>
   AccessFileName .htaccess
</VirtualHost>
```

I've thrown random junk into my htaccess and I do not get a 500 error so I know its not getting read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document root is:

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs
```

And your `<Directory>` container is for:

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/vhosts/
```

Are those supposed to be different? If your htaccess file is in the `httpdocs` directory, then that directory doesn't have the `AllowOverride All` associated with it. If your htaccess file is in the `vhosts` directory, then it's not being accessed when you go to your website.

Comment: Thanks so much, those 12 hour days of coding are starting to get to me.